# Which Server/Protocol should I use to create real time interactive online game in Flash?

Tags: flash

I'm totally noob in flash development and I"m now looking into multiplayer online game in Flash. What I found out are...

```
**Commercial One-stop Servers**
Electro Server (http://www.electro-server.com/)
Pulse (http://www.gamantra.com/pulse/)

**Free**
Openfire (XMPP Server) and Red5 Plugin
Hemlock (http://hemlock-kills.com/)
```

I excluted **amfphp** because it is not designed for multiplayer gaming if I'm not mistaken.

So my questions is **what should I choose to start my game**? Please share your knowledge and I'm really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The two most **popular servers** right now (April 2011) are:
**ElectoTank** - http://www.electrotank.com/eup.html
**SmartFox** - http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

I have personally used ElectroTank a I really liked it. If your project is of limited scope with no commercial ambitions, the choice is up to you. 
But if you are a small group or single develper, the support and documentation provided by the commercial products may be worth the cost to you.

Also there are a few **websites with their own multiplayer API**'s that you can use. This might be the very best approach for a "noob" to flash game development. 
For example:
**nonoba** - http://www.nonoba.com/developers/multiplayerapi/overview
**whirled** - http://www.whirled.com/

In this case you don't even need to set up a server, and there are no costs associated with using their APIs.